# Submit form from an offline webpage to server using jquery

Tags: jquery, form-submit, offline

I have created an HTML Autorun which run from a CD, there is a contact form in it. How can I submit it to my server? I think the common orgin problem is creating issues for me. None if the jquery  ways seems to work.

**UPDATE:**
I want to submit by ajax, jquery will first check if internet is connected and then submit. The autorun will be loaded in XULRunner bundled in the CD so running javascript won't be an issue.

Comment: there might be some security issues as javascript is disable...on such events even when you try to open from a zip file. (just a suggestion) that on your mind have you tried to point the action="server_url" ?

Comment: The autorun is running on XUL runner which is bundled in the cd.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that the traditional

```
<form method="post" action="http://yoursite.com/contact.php">
```

should work. Altough I never sent data to another domain like that before.

Comment: A regular form will work. The ajax thing won't because of the common origin policy.

Comment: Yeah, my thoughts exactly. What I wasn't sure of is putting a full URL as the action attribute, I never did that before. Thanks for clearing it up!

Comment: So there is no way to pass by ajax? Any workaround? To pass by get?

Comment: Get is still an ajax method. Why would you necessarilly need Ajax anyway? If you really want an alternative, I think you can open a pop-up with the params in the URL and make that self.close() after the request is sent...

Comment: So how will that be? I know how to open a popup and I know how to submit a form. But how do you submit a form through popup?

Comment: Did u mean something like  var value = $(.name).val(); var url="http://som.com?q=" + value;
window.open (url,"mywindow");

Comment: When you open a popup, you can pass the URL of the window you want to open, right? So you can simply open a pop-up with the address http://example.com/contact.php?name=something&email=something_else&msg=mesasge for example. Yes, the way of retrieving the values from the form are as you mentioned, just that instead of $(.name).val(); you'd have $('.name').val(); (with quotes), that if you already assigned a class 'name' to the field containing the name. Then you can use $_GET in PHP to retrieve variables from the URL, for example.

Answer (score 1):

How about this idea?

Have a Shortcut which will open the contact form hosted in your site in a web browser.Users can then submit their details via the online form.